# Extract text from specific HTML tag

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm coding little script and I've faced this problem

now I have this HTML code

```html
<div class="domains">
       <ul>
  <li class="noMessages">
<a href="select-admin-domain.do?domain=ex1.com">ex1.com</a>
          </li>
<li class="noMessages">
<a href="select-admin-domain.do?domain=ex2.com">ex2.com</a>
      </li>
<li class="cpCurrentDomain noMessages">
<a href="select-admin-domain.do?domain=ex3.com">ex3.com</a>
      </li>
<li class="noMessages">
<a href="select-admin-domain.do?domain=ex4.com">ex4.com</a>
          </li>
        
       </ul>
      </div>
```

now i want to extract the text from all this html tag using PHP

```
<a href="select-admin-domain.do?domain=ex1.com">ex1.com</a>
<a href="select-admin-domain.do?domain=ex2.com">ex2.com</a>
<a href="select-admin-domain.do?domain=ex3.com">ex3.com</a>
<a href="select-admin-domain.do?domain=ex4.com">ex4.com</a>
```

so the output become 
ex1.com
ex2.com
etc..

i've make this code

```html
<?php
function GetStr($string,$start,$end){
    
        
    
    $str = explode($start, $string);
    $str = explode($end, $str[1]);
    echo $str[0];
    
    
}
$ss= getStr($htmlcode,'<a href="select-admin-domain.do?domain=','">');

echo $ss;
```

it works good but it only gives me  the first output
ex1.com
and I want to echo all of them not just 1

Comment: Do not use regex use `HTML/DOM` parser for parsing `HTML`

Comment: How do you get you links? Are they generated by PHP? post more code to get you better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple regex to match `<a>` tags containing a link to `select-admin-domain.do`

For example:

```php
$re = '/<a href="select-admin-domain.do.*?">(.*?)<\/a>/';
if (preg_match_all($re, $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)) {
    var_dump(array_column($matches, 1));
}

// Outputs
//    array(4) {
//        [0] =>
//      string(7) "ex1.com"
//        [1] =>
//      string(7) "ex2.com"
//        [2] =>
//      string(7) "ex3.com"
//        [3] =>
//      string(7) "ex4.com"
//    }
```

Comment: nstead of using `array_column`, remove the two last parameters of `preg_match_all`, the result is in `$matches[1]`

Answer (score 0):

If you have in your `$string` var a `(string)` containig a html code and you want to get a each link href, or text you can use this code too:

```
//$string var containt html
echo strip_tags($string);

//output
ex1.com ex2.com ex3.com ex4.com
```